# Differences between linear airy wave theory and Stokes' 5 wave theory? and it's application

Tags: oceanography

What is the difference between linear airy wave theory and 5th order Stokes wave theory? What is the differences in terms of application. I am looking more on offshore structure analysis aspects.

Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

You should find what you're after within the following:

https://rules.dnvgl.com/docs/pdf/DNV/codes/docs/2014-04/RP-C205.pdf

If not, one of their other documents should contain the information.
I hope this finds you well.

Comment: Welcome to EarthScience.SE! Please try to answer the question in your post instead of posting an URL to a document.